# Local Ring mod Unique Maximal Ideal for a Discrete Valuation Ring (DVR)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose I have a discrete valuation ring $R$ with unique prime (i.e. maximal in this case) ideal $\mathfrak{m} = <t>$ (where $t\in R$ is the unique generator of $\mathfrak{m}$ up to multiplication by a unit). Then is it true that:

$R_{\mathfrak{m}}/\mathfrak{m} = R^\times\cup\{0\}$? My reasoning here is that localizing $R$ at $\mathfrak{m}$ does nothing, since we have that every element outside of $\mathfrak{m}$ is *already* a unit in $R$. And then just mod'ing out by $\mathfrak{m}$ gives $R/\mathfrak{m}$ with elements of the form $u + \mathfrak{m}$ for some unit $u\in R^\times$. I'm thinking that we just kinda...throw the 0 element into $R^\times$ by using the maximal ideal as the 0 element...

Anyone wanna tell me if I'm crazy and have just been looking at math for too many hours straight? :P

Comment: It’s certainly true that $R_{\mathfrak m}=R$ when $R$ is a local ring. But your argument is wrong because different elements of $R^\times$ may well be congruent to each other modulo $\mathfrak m$, and thus correspond to the same element in $R/\mathfrak m$.

Comment: Ah I see now. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $R=\mathbb{Z}_p$, the $p$-adic integers:
$$R=\left\{\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ip^i:a_i\in\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}\right\}$$which is a DVR with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}=p\mathbb{Z}_p$,
$$\mathfrak{m}=\left\{\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ip^i\in R:a_0=0\right\}$$
and units
$$R^\times=\left\{\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ip^i\in R:a_0\neq 0\right\}.$$
Note that $R_\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}R_\mathfrak{m}\cong R/\mathfrak{m}\cong\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is very different from $R^\times\cup\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Any suggestions on how to get a handle on $R_{\mathfrak{m}}/\mathfrak{m}R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ then? I'm trying to consider Frac$(R)\times R_{\mathfrak{m}}/\mathfrak{m}R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ and show that it is a finitely-generated $R$-algebra. I don't want anyone to show me the proof of that. Just trying to get a handle on $R_{\mathfrak{m}}/\mathfrak{m}R_{\mathfrak{m}}$.